# Every page on the site has a standard template installed, and you can't change it. Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a site on wordpress, and several templates, and at one point there was a bug(?), and all pages began to use the standard template, although in the editor is different

I've tried changing the theme, and disabling/enabling plugins

The site uses a lot of wp-bakery, acf

If anyone has encountered this, I would welcome your help!